# password validation and UNICODE

Tags: java, regex, passwords, pattern-matching

How to validate regex for condition:
Password must not contain any sequence of characters immediately followed by the same sequence of characters.  I am having other conditions as well and am using

```
(?=.*(..+)\\1)
```

to validate for immediate sequence repeat.  And it is failing.  This piece of code returns "true" for 3rd and 4th strings passed; I need it to return false.  Please help.

```
String s2[] = {"1newAb", "newAB1", "1234567AaAa", "123456ab3434", "love", "love1"}; 
    boolean b3;
    for(int i=0; i<s2.length; i++){
        b3 = s2[i].matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*(..+)\\1).{5,12}$");
        System.out.println("value" + b3);
    }
```

Comment: Learn to use the Regex master's secret weapon - online testing tools! -> http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/index.html (google 'regex tester' for more options).

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: While this can be a good exercise to learn regexes, you'd better split the password checking for each rule and use regexes only where needed, to improve code maintenance and readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) `(?!.*(.{2,})\\1)`.

For those who are wondering what `\\1` is: it represents match from group 1, which in our case is match from `(.{2,})`

Comment: I actully need any sequence (but my initial code i was trying 2 chars at a time).  I tried this and it didn't work for 2 char either.  I have added this into my code and it failed; it returned false for "ADOALDO"  Here's my pattern. 
b3 = s2[i].matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.{2,})\\1).{5,12}$");

Comment: @user1769790 It seems that your pattern returns false for `ADOALDO` because it doesn't contain any number

Comment: you are correct I checked it now; it was my bad. Thank you.  I am going ahead with breakup of code per rules; I am thinking to display error messages for each split of regex.  Am adding UNICODE as well and your regex worked well for UNICODE as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With Ron's suggestion I found which methods in java helps; matches(), find() work differently. find() helped me.
Guido's suggestion am breaking up code for different rules.  Here's my code; yet to refine it:  For checking repeat of any sequence using (\S+?)\1

```
String regex = "(\\S+?)\\1";
        String regex2 = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{5,12}$";
        p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        for (String str : s2) {
            matcher = p.matcher(str);
           if (matcher.find())
              System.out.println(str + " got repeated: " + matcher.group(1));
           else if(str.matches(regex2))
               System.out.println(str + " Password correct");
           else
               System.out.println(str + " Password incorrect");

        }
```